# output every attribute, value in an uneven JSON object

Tags: python, json

I have a very long and uneven JSON object and I want to output every attribute, value for the end points (leaves) of the object.

For instance, it could look like this:

```
data = {
    "Response": {
        "Version": "2.0",
        "Detail": {
            "TransactionID": "Ib410c-2",
            "Timestamp": "04:00"
        },
        "Transaction": {
            "Severity": "Info",
            "ID": "2222",
            "Text": "Success"
        },
        "Detail": {
            "InquiryDetail": {
                "Value": "804",
                "CountryISOAlpha2Code": "US"
            },
            "Product": {
                "ID": "PRD",
                "Org": {
                    "Header": {
                        "valuer": "804"
                    },
                    "Location": {
                        "Address": [
                            {
                                "CountryISOAlpha2Code": "US",
                                "Address": [
                                    {
                                        "Text": {
                                            "@Value": 2,
                                            "$": "Hill St"
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to output each potential leaf. It can output the (final attribute or the entire path) and the value.

I know I just need to add something to this:

```
data = json.loads(inputFile)
small = repeat(data)
for attribute,value in small.iteritems():
    print attribute,value
```

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate, but closely related: [Return a list of all variable names in a python nested dict/json document in dot notation](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17952981/1014938)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use recursion:

```
def print_leaf_keyvalues(d):
    for key, value in d.iteritems():
        if hasattr(value, 'iteritems'):
            # recurse into nested dictionary
            print_leaf_keyvalues(value)
        else:
            print key, value
```

Demo on your sample data:

```
>>> print_leaf_keyvalues(data)
Version 2.0
valuer 804
Address [{'CountryISOAlpha2Code': 'US', 'Address': [{'Text': {'@Value': 2, '$': 'Hill St'}}]}]
ID PRD
CountryISOAlpha2Code US
Value 804
Text Success
Severity Info
ID 2222
```

This will not handle the list value of `Address` however. You can always add an additional test for sequences and iterate and recurse again.

Comment: +1 But why prefer `hasattr(value, 'iteritems')` over `isinstance(value, dict)`?

Comment: @That1Guy: I prefer duck typing; all you need for the recursive call is an object that supports `iteritems()`; it doesn't matter what other methods are supported here.

Comment: what if you wanted to go further into it? For instance, expanding the Address into: CountryISOAlpha2Code: US, @Value:2, $:Hill St

Comment: @user1889575: then you'd have to expand the recursive function to handle lists.